# android gcm ccs (xmpp) connection

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp

hi i am very new to gcm and ccs i have successfully set up and run gcm using php now i am setting up with ccs(xmpp) now can anyone tell where to add receiver id

```
new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString("my_message", "Hello World");
                    data.putString("my_action","SAY_HELLO");
                    String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
                    gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
                    msg = "Sent message";
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
```

Comment: You may want to check on [GCM Guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm). It also includes the concepts and guide in implementing [CCS/XMPP](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs) connection server

Comment: It seems that you are trying to send an upstream message. For that case the receiver will be the server. This code  `gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);` means you are sending it to the server of the SENDER_ID.